# Missing records in Kafka Streams foreign-key join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka Streams application performing a foreign-key (inner) join.

The input data is created by debezium postgres connector.

On startup the application consumes records of the left topic (with ~3.7Mio records) and ~30Mio records of the right topic. There should be a right record for each of the left records.

In a first run 4298 of the expected messages are missing.
In a second run 1840 of the expected messages are missing.
There is no overlap between the missing messages of the two runs.

**Our Data (simplified)**
Left topic:
key: {"pk_entity": 123}, value: {"fk_subject_info": 456, ...}

Right topic:
key: {"id": "i456"}, value: {"foo": "bar"}

**Foreign key extractor**
Transforms {"fk_subject_info": 456, ...} to {"id": "i456"}

**Analysis**

According to this [post about foreign-key joins](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-enrichment-with-kafka-streams-foreign-key-joins/), the join creates a subscription topic where the key is the value returned by the foreign key extractor and a response topic where the keys is the one of the left topic.

When we analyze on the level of individual missing records, we see different cases:

**Case 1**
Right record is missing.

left topic:
key: {"pk_entity": 84793}, value: {"fk_subject_info": 84792}

subscription-registration-topic:
key {"id":"i84792"} is present

right topic:
key {"id":"i84792"} is missing

Here the join can't work since input data is missing. This case is not directly relevant to the question, but it could give hints on a general problem in our infrastructure.

**Case 2**
Response is missing.

left topic:
key: {"pk_entity": 1658195}, value: {"fk_subject_info": 1658191}

subscription-registration-topic:
key {"id":"i1658191"} is present

right topic:
key {"id":"i1658191"} is present

subscription-response-topic
key {"pk_entity": 1658195} is missing

In this case left and right messages are present. Join should work, but the subscription response is missing.

We invested hours in solving the problem. Since we can't find any pattern in the missing data, we expect the problem to be related to the configuration of the application or the kafka cluster.

We monitored cpu and memory consumption of the containers (running on kubernetes) and we scanned the logs on the application for warnings or errors.

We did not find anything that could point us to the source of the problem.

Comment: How do you represent the left and the right topics in your Kafka Streams app? E.g. KTable and Ktable, KStream and Ktable etc.

Comment: @Michal: Both input topics are represented as KTables.

Comment: I found a similar issue in the confluent community forum: https://forum.confluent.io/t/intermittent-data-loss-under-high-volume-with-aggregation-after-map-or-groupby-rekey-repartition-with-log-compaction-enabled/4388/2

Comment: We also have topic.cleanup.policy=compact enabled and quite aggressive compaction settings (every 30 Minutes). 

This affects also the inner subscription-registration and subscription-response topics.

Could this cause the problem with joins?

Comment: I'm not certain about that but for example on Confluent Cloud fk join subscription registration and subscription response topic are configured by default with cleanup.policy = "delete" and retention.ms = -1.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but we also seem to be loosing records using a foreign key join. I asked in Confluent's Slack (https://confluentcommunity.slack.com/archives/C48AHTCUQ/p1677160967824089):

We think this may happen under heavy pressure, but it is difficult to say.

We have tried hard to reproduce this. The best I could get is this test (in a fork of the Kafka repo):
[KTableKTableForeignKeyJoinDistributedTest.java](https://github.com/agile-jordi/kafka/blob/foreign_key_join_missing_records_test/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/KTableKTableForeignKeyJoinDistributedTest.java)

In this test:

- I use test containers to test against an actual broker (I'm not sure whether it would reproduce the error with EmbeddedKafkaCluster)
- I have a simple foreign key join between 2 streams (using the last letter of the string value of the left as the foreign key join)
- I send a (big-ish) set of fixed data to the left stream and 5 records to the right stream.
- I wait until the lag gets to 0 AND all the expected records are read

The configuration I use for KafkaStreams is a bit extreme in order to have the app struggle to process the records. There are missed heartbeats and rebalances. The reason for this configuration is that I would expect that to happen every now and then in production and still don't miss records and I wasn't unable to reproduce the issue with more usual configuration values.

On my machine, aprox. 1 out of every 10 executions of the test shows:

- Lag 0
- But missing records in the output stream

Comment: We observed that more threads lead to less missing messages. this may support your hypothesis, that message loss might happen under heavy pressure. Can you share, what you mean by extreme configs?

Comment: The configuration [here](https://github.com/agile-jordi/kafka/blob/foreign_key_join_missing_records_test/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/KTableKTableForeignKeyJoinDistributedTest.java#L166) is chosen on purpose to provoke lost heartbeats and, ultimately, rebalances. Depending on the HW used to run the test, I needed to fine tune the parameters to get test failures. But I got them even when the reported lag is 0.